# Google SignIn Using Firebase In Capacitor Generating Error "auth/argumement-error"

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic2, capacitor

- Getting this error when trying to login. I have set the auth
  initialization as recommend.
- Works fine in the browser

```
// initializing auth
if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
    auth = initializeAuth(app, {
        persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence,
    });
} else {
    auth = getAuth(app);
}
```

Making the login call

```
export const fbGoogleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
        if (result) {
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result)
            return {
                token: credential?.accessToken,
                user: result.user
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        // The AuthCredential type that was used.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error as any);
        console.log("credential", credential);
        return {
            error,
            credential
        }
    }
}
```

hopefully, the answer isn’t just to use the plugin

thanks in advance